# Deploy QT apps in Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt4

I have created an app in QT & I am able to deploy it in Windows. 
But in Mac I am facing problems.
Can any one help me how to do this?

I am using the commands as said in help files & when I type `qmake -config release`  i get `::::"Failure to open file: /Developer/Examples/Qt/mainwindows/application///application.xcodeproj/project.p­bxproj Unable to generate makefile for: /Developer/Examples/Qt/mainwindows/application/application.pro"`

Comment: It might be helpful to know what the problem is, to help you.

Comment: first prob is that.I am using Qt 4.7 which is installed automatically, So which method will be useful for deploying i.e. static build or framework build cause I am using QSql plugins in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the lack of information regarding the problem that you are facing I can only recomend you to read the info provided in the Qt Reference Documentation.

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/deployment-mac.html

Comment: i am getting confused with static & framework build..which I will use as I am using Qsql plugins.

Comment: I tried Framework build..but I got stuck with this : " otool -L QtGui.framework/QtGui" what does i have to do in this case?

Comment: I am using the commands as said & when I type  qmake -config release : i get ::::"Failure to open file: /Developer/Examples/Qt/mainwindows/application///application.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
Unable to generate makefile for: /Developer/Examples/Qt/mainwindows/application/application.pro"

Comment: Can't you just build your project, and then use /Developer/Tools/Qt/macdeployqt tool ?